# Error from server (NotFound): pods "$(kubectl" not found

Tags: awk, kubernetes, hyperledger, minikube, hyperledger-sawtooth

In the minikube hyper-v machine I did deployment of sawtooth-0, using [sawtooth config file](https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/sawtooth-kubernetes-default.yaml).

Now when I am checking running pods it seems to have some default ones but while trying to connect with the kubernetes shell container.

```
C:\Users\Debo>kubectl get --all-namespaces
You must specify the type of resource to get. Use "kubectl api-resources" for a complete list of supported resources.

error: Required resource not specified.
Use "kubectl explain <resource>" for a detailed description of that resource (e.g. kubectl explain pods).
See 'kubectl get -h' for help and examples

C:\Users\Debo>kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE              NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default                sawtooth-0-65d547498c-mfrsb                  7/7     Running   1          120m
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-b684l                     1/1     Running   0          122m
kube-system            coredns-6955765f44-tc4vg                     1/1     Running   0          122m
kube-system            etcd-minikube                                1/1     Running   0          121m
kube-system            kube-addon-manager-minikube                  1/1     Running   0          121m
kube-system            kube-apiserver-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          121m
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-minikube             1/1     Running   0          121m
kube-system            kube-proxy-t7nhs                             1/1     Running   0          122m
kube-system            kube-scheduler-minikube                      1/1     Running   0          121m
kube-system            storage-provisioner                          1/1     Running   0          122m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-7b64584c5c-b8t7s   1/1     Running   0          122m
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-79d9cd965-pn94z         1/1     Running   0          122m

C:\Users\Debo>kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
sawtooth-0-65d547498c-mfrsb   7/7     Running   1          120m

C:\Users\Debo>kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | awk "/sawtooth-0/ {print $1}") --container sawtooth-shell -- bash
awk: /sawtooth-0/ {print $1})
awk:                        ^ syntax error
errcount: 1
Error from server (NotFound): pods "$(kubectl" not found

C:\Users\Debo>
```

Comment: Try the `awk` command in single quotes - `awk '/sawtooth-0/ {print $1}'` or do `awk "/sawtooth-0/ {print \$1}"`

Comment: ```
C:\Users\Debo>kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | awk '/sawtooth-0/ {print $1}') --container sawtooth-shell -- bash
awk: '/sawtooth-0/
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
Error from server (NotFound): pods "$(kubectl" not found

C:\Users\Debo>kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods | awk "/sawtooth-0/ {print \$1}") --container sawtooth-shell -- bash
awk: /sawtooth-0/ {print \$1})
awk:                     ^ backslash not last character on line
Error from server (NotFound): pods "$(kubectl" not found
```
not working bro

Comment: That looks like a Windows command prompt, but Unix Bourne shell syntax.  What shell are you actually using, and does it support Bourne shell `$(command)` substitution syntax?

Comment: (`kubectl get pods -o name` might be more robust than that `awk` invocation; also consider filtering by label `kubectl get pods -l app=sawtooth` or similar to avoid needing an `awk`/`grep`/`sed` step.)

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve? Kubernetes have many built-in commands. If you want to connect to specific container from sawtooth pod you can just use `kubectl exec -ti sawtooth-0-65d547498c-mfrsb -c <container_name> /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

**If i understand your use case you are trying to filter the sawtooth-0 pod from list of give pods in a namespace and then open a interactive session toward container running inside it where you know the container name.**

So to solve above i took the  sawtooth config file attached in question and started two instance of it sawtooth-0 and sawtooth-1 alongside few of dummy pods then i use this command on windows power shell to filter and connect to container on sawtooth-0 pod.

**All below was done assuming you need kubectl running on windows powershell**

```
PS C:\Users\winuser> kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox                       1/1     Running   0          4m18s
nginx                         1/1     Running   0          10m
sawtooth-0-7f584587cf-8jfwk   7/7     Running   0          19m
sawtooth-1-6ccd4494-kq24n     7/7     Running   0          18m
```

**Connecting to sawtooth-0**

```
PS C:\Users\winuser> kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | findstr -i sawtooth-0) --container sawtooth-shell -- bash
root@sawtooth-0-7f584587cf-8jfwk:/# whoami
root
root@sawtooth-0-7f584587cf-8jfwk:/# date
Thu Jan 16 11:57:22 UTC 2020
root@sawtooth-0-7f584587cf-8jfwk:/# exit
exit
command terminated with exit code 130
```

**Connecting to sawtooth-1**

```
PS C:\Users\winuser> kubectl exec -it $(kubectl get pods --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name" | findstr -i sawtooth-1) --container sawtooth-shell -- bash
root@sawtooth-1-6ccd4494-kq24n:/# date
Thu Jan 16 12:17:33 UTC 2020
```

Comment: just a offtopic - it seems kubectl exec requires container name (irrespective of we specified or not) . Isnt there a way to just connect the pod ( and not the container) ?